Unable to get Laravel Spatie/Browsershot working with Puppeteer, Ubuntu 24.04, PHP 8.3, Chrom & Nginx
Environment:

PHP 8.3
Laravel 11
Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
NGINX
Node (v18.19.1) (latest for today)
Spatie/Browsershot (Puppeteer, Chrome 128.0.6613.119)

Issues:

Spatie wanting me to install outdated Node/Puppeteer versions (https://spatie.be/docs/browsershot/v4/requirements). And we all want the latest.
Even if we follow Spatie instructions, we get Permissions errors (www-data user cannot run Chrome or has no permissions to create temp directories).
Other Chrome versions (chromium-browser or non-snap .deb installations) methods do not work (php8.3-fpm does not belong to Snap cgroup or other issues with permissions).
Since we want to use the latest soft versions, some packages are missing.


Please share a [mcve] (code, package.json, composer.json, commands you ran, etc) and ask one specific question. I understand this question is a strawman to facilitate your self answer, but the question still needs to abide by the site rules and be answerable by other users. Thanks.

How to make it work ("This is the way"):

Install LEMP. Just as you usually do.

Create a real www-data user with /home/www-data directory.



Crete directory: sudo mkdir /home/www-data
Stop NGINX and php-fpm: sudo service nginx stop, sudo service php8.3-fpm stop
Change www-data user settings: sudo usermod -d /home/www-data www-data -s /bin/bash
Maybe kill user related processes kill {proocess_id}
Start NGINX and php-fpm: sudo service nginx start, sudo service php8.3-fpm start


Install Laravel into /home/www-data/laravel directory.

Install Puppeteer globally.



Install node and npm: sudo apt install nodejs, sudo apt install npm
Install Puppeteer: npm install puppeteer --location=global
Install related soft: gconf-service, libasound2, libatk1.0-0, libc6, libcairo2, libcups2, libdbus-1-3, libexpat1, libfontconfig1, libgbm1, libgcc1, libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0, libglib2.0-0, libgtk-3-0, libnspr4, libpango-1.0-0, libpangocairo-1.0-0, libstdc++6, libx11-6, libx11-xcb1, libxcb1, libxcomposite1, libxcursor1, libxdamage1, libxext6, libxfixes3, libxi6, libxrandr2, libxrender1, libxss1, libxtst6, ca-certificates, fonts-liberation, libnss3, lsb-release, xdg-utils, wget, libgbm-dev, libxshmfence-dev, libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0, liboss4-salsa-asound2, alsa.
Install it as sudo apt-get install -y {package_name}. I found some issues when trying to install it in a bulky way, so I recommend installing it one by one to make sure everything is installed.


Ask Puppeteer to install Chrome browser.
Run: sudo -u www-data npx puppeteer browsers install chrome
When it’s done, you will see the Chrome file location. For me it was: /home/www-data/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-128.0.6613.119/chrome-linux64/chrome. Use this path in your code with Browsershot: ->setChromePath("/home/www-data/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-128.0.6613.119/chrome-linux64/chrome")

Use Puppeteer Chrome browser to generate PDF.


Browsershot::html($html)
            ->setOption('args', ['--disable-web-security'])
            ->ignoreHttpsErrors()
            ->noSandbox()
            ->setCustomTempPath('/home/www-data/browsershot-html')
            ->addChromiumArguments([
                'lang' => "en-US,en;q=0.9",
                'hide-scrollbars',
                'enable-font-antialiasing',
                'force-device-scale-factor' => 1,
                'font-render-hinting' => 'none',
                'user-data-dir' => '/home/www-data/user-data',
                'disk-cache-dir' => '/home/www-data/user-data/Default/Cache',
            ])
->setChromePath("/home/www-data/.cache/puppeteer/chrome/linux-128.0.6613.119/chrome-linux64/chrome")
            ->newHeadless()
            ->showBackground()
            ->savePdf($tmp_file);

You may not use some options from the example above to make your PDF generation more secure. Feel free to adjust it for your needs.
Hope my struggles will help someone save time.
This answer helped me a lot:
Unable to get Laravel Browsershot working with Puppeteer Ubuntu 20.04 Arm PHP 8.2 with Snap Chromium & Nginx

Thanks for the effort you put into this answer, but why not add it to the existing question? Then again, the other "question" is also not a question, so both are off-topic. Also, why not provide all commands exactly as a script rather than expecting the user to piece them together and probably mess a few of them up?

I'm using a laravel forge provisioned server, as such don't tamper with www or www-data and everything on the forge server is isolate to a "forge" group. Seems like just adding the user to the group worked for me:
Anyone sees an issue with this approach?
sudo chown -R forge:forge /snap/bin/chromium

